# Top crop with ImageLoader - Android

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I'm loading images from URLs into my ImageView like so -

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(url, imageview, display-options)
```

Now I would like to crop the image to the center top. I tried using https://gist.github.com/arriolac/3843346 but I think it expects the image via a drawable and I want to use ImageLoader to set the image.

Can somebody help me understand if I can use https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-query/ (Android Query) in conjunction with ImageLoader?

Is there any way to handle cropping in Android (apart from centerCrop) natively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your ImageView with ProfileImageView and enjoy the view :)

```
public class ProfileImageView extends ImageView {
private Bitmap bm;

public ProfileImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    bm = null;
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    if (bm != null) {
        setImageBitmap(bm);
        bm = null;
    }
}

@Override
public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
    int viewWidth = getWidth();
    int viewHeight = getHeight();
    if (viewWidth == 0 || viewHeight == 0) {
        this.bm = bm;
        return;
    }
    setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

    Matrix m = getImageMatrix();
    m.reset();
    int min = Math.min(bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight());
    int cut;
    if (bm.getWidth() > viewWidth && bm.getWidth() > bm.getHeight()) {
        cut = Math.round((bm.getWidth() - viewWidth) / 2.f);
    } else {
        cut = 0;
    }
    RectF drawableRect = new RectF(cut, 0, min - cut, min);

    RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight);
    m.setRectToRect(drawableRect, viewRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.START);
    setImageMatrix(m);
    super.setImageBitmap(bm);
}
```

}